# Dom parsing issue empty result

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

```
<tr class='Jed01'>
<td height='20' class='JEDResult'>1</td>
<td height='30' class='JEDResult'>26.04.2013</td>
<td height='30' class='JEDResult'>19:43</td>
<td height='30' class='JEDResult'>Processing</td>
<td height='30' class='JEDResult'><a href="#" pressed="GetInfo(1233);" title=''>Jeddah</a></td>
</tr>
```

Result = first step - date - time - state - place

First of all I am new to PHP and I am trying to parse this data to my web via PHP - DOM as recommended to me before on Stackoverflow. In the code below I have called all classes to get data but I can't get any result while there is no any issue. So please where it could be my issue?

Thanks from now

```
<?php

$input = "www.kalkatawi.com/luai.html"
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($input);


foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr)
{
  if($tr->getAttribute('class') == 'Jed01')
  {
    foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td)
    {
      if($td->getAttribute('class') == 'JEDResult')
      {
        echo ($td->nodeValue);
      }
    }     
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors in the first code line: `$input = 'MyLink';`

Comment: `loadHTML` expects `$input` *itself* to be HTML, which in your example it is not. What's going on?

Comment: Wonder how this syntax error could not be seen from the author? Writing on notepad?

Comment: And you also forgot a semicolon after `echo($td)`

Comment: @jon I think he means its being loaded via `file_get_contents` from a link he doesn't want to share :)

Comment: To whoever fixed the code in the question: please change it back, syntax errors also cause problems...

Comment: @Dom: In that case, he should be using `loadHTMLFile` to make that clear. At least in the example code.

Comment: @Jon: Agreed, just trying to clarify for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dont forget those semi colons ;)**

Try this;

```
<?php

$input = file_get_contents("http://www.kalkatawi.com/luai.html");
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($input);


foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr)
{
  if($tr->getAttribute('class') == 'Jed01')
  {
    foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td)
    {
      if($td->getAttribute('class') == 'JEDResult')
      {
        echo ($td->nodeValue);
        echo '<br/>';
      }
    }     
  }
  echo '<br/><br/>';
}

?>
```

Should output;

```
1
26.04.2013
19:43
Processing
Jeddah


2
26.04.2013
20:43
Printed
RIY
```

Comment: Thanks I have edited but nothing happen. I have also added my link if you want to check. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code.

**Loading the HTML**

```
$input = 'MyLink';
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($input);
```

This code attempts to treat the string `'MyLink'` as HTML, which obviously it is not. If that's your actual code then nothing would work beyond this point. Either provide proper HTML input or use `loadHTMLFile` to load HTML from a file.

**Comparisons are case-sensitive**

On the one hand there is this:

```
<tr class='Jed01'>
```

And on the other this:

```
if($tr->getAttribute('class') == 'JED01')
```

Since `'Jed01'` != `'JED01'` this will never be `true`. Either fix the casing or use some other mechanism such as `stricmp` to compare the classes.

**Objects cannot be printed**

This results in a fatal error:

```
echo ($td);
```

What it should be instead: most likely `echo $td->nodeValue`, but other possibilities are open depending on what you want to do.

**But you could do it much more easily with XPath**

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$query = "//tr[@class='Jed01']//td[@class='JEDResult']"; // google XPath syntax

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    print_r($node->nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon. I have edited from JEF01 to Jed01 and echo but nothing changed. Thanks again I need help.